# Rails Engines with separate DB's

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multiple-databases, rails-engines

I can't find anything by [googling](http://www.google.ca/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=rails+engines+separate+database&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&redir_esc=&ei=5HILTcu5NMyknQeK7vjuDQ) this topic.  I'm tasked with combining two rails apps into one using Rails engines (v2.3.10).  I'm trying to migrate the one app's db over to the other.  My initial thought was to write a migration that incorporates the use of multiple databases using a similar method [posted here](http://www.messaliberty.com/2009/02/ruby-how-to-use-multiple-databases-with-activerecord/).

Basically, load up the db config and define two AR classes, one for each db, then subclass those AR classes with my table classes. Then I can just iterate through all the stuff in the original app db and add to new db (with modifications to match new schema)

Then I thought i'd be easier if Engines had some sort of built in support OR if there was a plugin of sorts that might ease this multi db connection.  I'm comfortable doing the work manually but thought I'd see if anyone knew of a good solution for this type of thing.

Just looking for a one off solution as eventually we'll access everything through the database that is being migrated over to

Comment: After you complete the migration is the intent that you will have all of the data in one database? Or will you need to keep accessing both databases separately?

Comment: all in one db, this is just a one off solution

Comment: This topic is now the first result for the Google search you posted. O_o

Comment: haha oh great... guess that means it will never be answered

Comment: Did you find any solution for that case ?